# What makes an operator "baryonic"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, gauge-theory, fermions

I am trying to work my way through [arXiv:1712.00020](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.00020), but there is a statement I don't quite get. On §2.6 (p. 21), the author claims that the simplest baryonic operator in the gauge theory $\mathrm{SU}(N)$ with $N_F$ fermions in the fundamental representation is
$$
\epsilon_{\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_N}\psi^{\alpha_1 B_1}\cdots\psi^{\alpha_N B_N}\tag{2.45}
$$
where $\alpha_i\in(1,N)$ are colour indices and $B_i\in(1,N_F)$ are flavour indices.

Surely I can construct simpler gauge-invariants out of the $\psi$'s, such as
$$
\bar\psi_{\alpha B}\Gamma\psi^{\alpha B'}
$$
or tensor products thereof, where $\Gamma$ is a matrix in spin space (e.g., $\Gamma=1$ or $\Gamma=\gamma^\mu$, corresponding to a quark mass term or a current $j^\mu\sim\bar\psi\gamma^\mu\psi$). Are these operators not "baryonic"? what defines a baryonic operator? Why is $(2.45)$ the simplest baryonic operator, as opposed to other presumably simpler gauge-invariant combinations of $\psi$'s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that it is just jargon. What they mean is – the simplest gauge-invariant operator that contains only $\psi$, not $\bar{\psi}$.

For the case of $SU(3)$, $N = 3$ and their operator becomes cubic in $\psi$. Thus it contains "three quarks", and can be thought of as the field operator for a baryon field (again, just jargon, actual physical baryons are complicated states in the non-linear theory).

Your operator contains $\bar{\psi}$, and thus cannot be called "baryonic". So I guess, the jargon for it is – "mesonic" :)

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I've been scratching my head for days. Cheers!